# PHP, GD library not works

Tags: php, gd

I have begun exploring of GDI functions in PHP. 
I wrote the following code

```
<?php 
echo"GDI FUNCTIONS"; 
$im=imageCreate(500,200);
$colorBg=imageColorAllocate($im,150,150,100);
$colorText=imageColorAllocate($im,0,0,0);
imageString($im,1, 20, 20, 'George', $colorText);
header("Content-type: image/gif");
imageGif($im);
imageDestroy($im);
?>
```

PHP 5.2.13
GD2 Extension in PHP.net exists;
I Have reinstalled php and have restarted apache server.

but still picture not displayed. I have tried in all browsers like (Google chrome, IE, opera and etc.). but only a little rectangle is displayd at left-upper corner.

Even text 'GDI FUNCTION' not displayed. (PHP works fine!!!)

PHP_info shows thad GD is enabled.

Comment: post your actual image display code

Comment: Testing your code, minus the `echo` and it appears to work ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are echoing text before sending a header. This results in a PHP warning and a invalid image binary. Simply remove `echo"GDI FUNCTIONS";` and it should work.

Also not that all (AFAIK) GD functions are lowercase.

Comment: If you try (exactly) the first example on http://php.net/imagegif, does that work?

Comment: I have found the solution.
I change encoding of page with UTF8-Withouth BOM. 
Thank you for your replays!!!!